# Load database records to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I make the database records that I have on my heroku app to be available also on my machine?

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: databasename
  pool: 5
  username: my_mac_username
  password: #no password filled

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  encoding: unicode
  database: testdatabasename
  pool: 5
  username: my_mac_username
  password: #no password filled

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: productiondatabasename
  pool: 5
  username: my_mac_username
  password: #no password filled
```

I run

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL productiondatabasename --app my_heroku_app_name
```

and bunch of lines is being displayed in my terminal. But that's it. Nothing more happens. I still do not have the records available on localhost.

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://blog.heroku.com/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong was the configuration of database.yml.

If using sqlite3, drop your db first, then change the development adapter to postgresql (make sure that you have installed it properly!). Then recreate the database.

After running

```
heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL developmentdatabasename --app my_heroku_app_name
```

everything should be OK!